# Error while select from a view in Teradata

Tags: view, teradata

I am getting error while doing a simple select * from a view. created a view successfully but getting this error on select :
non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group

I tried to insert the result set in table and it was successful and even select worked for that table.
For same set of select statements the view creation was successful and the select failed(select * from viewname)

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Can you post the view syntax or a modified copy of the syntax if you can't disclose the object names? There could be a couple factors at play here with using aggregates or GROUP BY to eliminate duplicates that is causing this error.

Comment: Thanks @RobPaller Sorry but its a very big piece of code and is cumbersome to convert. can you please suggest something how from same set of select statements rows get inserted to table successfully and select is successful.Also a view is created successfully but select is unsuccessful. Also there is no group by clause in  the group of select statements from which table or view was created.

Comment: Is there an aggregate function being used somewhere in the view your are querying or a view being referenced by this view?